# Any Perl http load test modules?

Tags: perl, cpan

Is there any Perl http load test modules? support concurrency, 'Number of requests to perform', sort of things?

Comment: This question mentions a number of free load test solutions.  I don't know of anything in Perl, but of course you could call an external tool in Perl from a system command.  http://serverfault.com/questions/2107/tools-for-load-testing-http-servers

Comment: In response to your deleted question, since I already wrote an answer: You're not actually doing any benchmarking and you don't want Benchmark's output, so why not just use `use Time::HiRes qw( time ); my $s = time; ... my $e = time; say(($e-$s)*1_000_000);`